# Returning object in NMOCK2

Tags: c#, nmock2

I am using NMOCK2 and I want my mock to return a List containing 1 element, . This is what I have written so far:

```
Expect.Once.On(mockDatabaseManager).
    Method("GetTablesNames").
    Will(Return.Value(new List<Result>()));
```

Is it even possible to do such thing, and if it is, how should I do that?

Definition of Result:

```
public class Result
{
    private Dictionary<String, Object> _result = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    public string GetString(String columnName)
    {
        return _result[columnName].ToString();
    }

    public double GetDouble(String columnName)
    {
        return Double.Parse(_result[columnName].ToString());
    }

    public int GetInteger(String columnName)
    {
        return int.Parse(_result[columnName].ToString());
    }

    public void Put(String columnName, Object value)
    {
        _result.Add(columnName, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new empty list by using this code:

```
new List<Result>()
```

If you want to create a list with a single element you can use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx):

```
new List<Result> { new Result() }
```

(The `Result` class wraps a dictionary. However, there seems to be no way to add entries to this dictionary so calling `new Result()` will create a pretty boring object but that may be just fine in a unit test.)

Comment: Thanks, that solves half of my problem. Unfortunately, I have to add an item to List, and Result does not have a constructor, and I can't change it. Is it possible to use Put method?

Comment: @MartaPanuszewska: All types always have constructors. With the code provided `Result` has a default constructor generated by the compiler and as I have pointed out you currently have no way to add elements to the dictionary. Either provide methods for that or create a suitable constructor.